# Visualizing car speed data in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates, position, speed

I have gathered positional (Long and Lat) data and the corresponding speed of a vehicle over a specific route. I am able to plot the X-Y coordinates in ArcMap 10.7 over a basemap which essentially shows my movement on the route. I would like to visualize the speed as well over the course.

How do I use the specifically color-coded symbol for each XY coordinate marking symbol?

Comment: So, you would want something to show the speed of vehicles based on colors, like for speed 60-80 mph red, 30-40 mph green? Also if possible add a screenshot for reference.

Comment: As  @YogeshChavan suggests, if you have the speed of vehicle attribute available in your dataset, you can color based on this attribute. Here is a link for inspiration 
https://eng.uber.com/kepler-data-visualization-traffic-safety/

Comment: With rule-based symbology you could also use thickness of the line as a mean to represent speed (or velocity). This could be easier to interpret for some viewers than colour. The drawback, of course, is that a road becomes "broader" in a sense.

Comment: @YogeshChavan Exactly that, either specific color for a certain range, or a changing hue of a color for increasing speed, whatever might that be. I have the corresponding speed at each XY point. I can not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use [graduated colors for your layer symbology](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-graduated-colors.htm), and symbolize your points based on the speed attribute field.